# Why is the result 'undefined' when using a variable holding an integer to access an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this attempt at a function here

```
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
    const someArray = []
    let count = 0

    for (const i of iterable) {
      if (i != someArray[count]) {
        console.log(someArray[count])
        someArray.push(i)
        count++
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }
    return someArray
  }

console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))
```

The problem:
When I use `someArray[1]` it will access the item in the array fine.
When I use `someArray[count]` where count holds an integer value the result is undefined. Am I missing something painfully obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to create a separate test script of

```
const someArray = ['a', 2, 'c', 4]
let count = 3

console.log(someArray[count])
```

and this works fine.

Can't figure out why in this scenario it would be considered 'undefined' when taking the same approach.

Comment: In your example, `count` is always `someArray.length`, by construction. `someArray[someArray.length]` is always `undefined`.

Comment: @jsN00b You did not merely add an executable code snippet. You changed the code, adding some things and apparently fixing the issue with the original code. Answers should never be edited into questions. I have rolled your edit back; do not make these types of edits again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the `someArray[count]` in the `if` statement always points **after** the end of the array.

Let's simulate some loops:

1. First loop, `count = 0`, `someArray = []`;

   ```
    someArray[0]; // is undefined because someArray is empty
   ```
2. Second loop, `count = 1`, `someArray = ['A']`

   ```
    someArray[1]; // is undefined because someArray only has 1 item, not 2
   ```
3. Third loop, `count = 2`, `someArray = ['A','A']`

   ```
    someArray[2]; // is undefined because someArray only has 2 items, not 3
   ```

etc.

Basically you have an off-by-one logic error.